# Font-Awesome not displaying

Tags: css, wordpress, font-awesome

I have checked and checked and I'm sure it's something simple I've overlooked but my font is not displaying.
The first paragraph is suppose to have quotes around it (you will see it has them right now because I did it without font-awesome); however, you will see the second full paragraph is suppose to have a quote at the beginning and it's not displaying.  Please help

http://dev.healthcaresolutionsteam.com/agent/barbara-scott/

Comment: What browser are you using? I do see the quote before it.

Comment: Is this issue still open? Because on your example site, it looks like you are not using Awesome anymore.

Answer (score 1):

Your CSS specificity is being overridden by a style in `style.css`.

Font-Awesome only has:

```
.fa { font-family: FontAwesome }
```

Yet your style overrides the `font-family` (note the `!important`):

```
#fake, .menu, a.signin span, .balloon_text, #footer, #footer a, #signin_menu p a, #learning_center h2, #hst_blog h2, #carriers h2, #career_center h2, #learning_center, #hst_blog, #carrier_careers, .entry-title, #sidebar, #sidebar a, .breadcrumbs a, .breadcrumbs, #searchform input, .page-title, .entry-content, .entry-content a, .entry-utility, .read_more, #content h1, #content h2, #content h3, #content h4, #content h5, #content h6, .widget-title, #live_chat a, #hst_careers, #apply_online, #sales_revenue, #hst_compensation, #search_agents, #search_map, .agent_search, #search-results, #usca-intro-text, .usca-plan, #usca-form {
    font-family: 'AllerRegular',Arial,Helvetica,sans-serif !important;
    font-weight: normal;
}
```

Desired style being overridden:

[image: Style being overridden]

Style actually being applied:

[image: Actual style being applied]

Comment: Brad, Thank you for your help.  I commented out the .entry-content css that was conflicting and the quote is still not displaying.  Do you see anything else this could be?

Comment: I did notice that it does not display in Firefox and IE only.

Comment: @user3254606: best thing you can do is what I've done. Use the debugger and inspect the quote icon. then see which style is being applied and which is being overridden (note strike-through on the style). Through process of elimination you'll get it working. ;-)

Answer (score 0):

Check, if you use selector *

```
*{font-family: Arial}
```

in your default stylesheet.